# Windows Service Timing Out Instantly

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have written a windows service in C#.  I am able to install and run it locally on my 64-bit Windows 7 machine.

When I install it on my remote virtual private server (Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard, 64-bit), I get the following:

"Error 1053: The MyService service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion"

The weird thing is that this message shows immediately.  It should take 30 seconds for such a message to show.

I have checked the windows event logs, and it shows me no further information.

Comment: Possibly a security issue.  Is the service accessing the file system and perhaps the account it is running under doesn't have access?

Comment: What does your service do in the start method?

Comment: Other issues may include method Main doing stuff before the Start method that the window's service start doesn't like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all your answers!

It turns out that I did not have .net framework 4.5 installed, and that is what I was targeting.

Still, it was a very strange error, and I am surprised it installed at all.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to set up the service to login to the server... here's what I had to do with mine

[image]

Right click on the service .. go to Properties and click the Log On tab.....

Then click the "This Account" radio button and enter the credentials for the server